# Enabling PowerShell ISE or OutGrid View, reboot required?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like to use an OutGrid View in one my powershell scripts. According to MSDN, in Windows Servers this feature is not enabled by default in PowerShell 2.0. Apparently, the only way to enable this feature is by [enabling Power Shell ISE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/guruketepalli/archive/2012/11/06/enable-powershell-ise-from-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) with this:

```
 Import-Module ServerManager 
 Add-WindowsFeature PowerShell-ISE
```

Is very common when you install or add a new Windows feature have to reboot machine.
I would like to enable this feature on my Windows server 2008 R2, but not sure if it will ask me to reboot or something. That server shoudn't be rebooted.
Is it safe to proceed?

Comment: Yes, it's safe per those instructions and it states it will not require a reboot. In the event it does require a reboot, it will not force you to reboot it right then so you'd be able to do so when it's safe to do so with coordination in your environment.

Comment: Yes, I did, and it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Enabling PowerShell ISE or OutGrid View, reboot required?**
>
> I would like to enable this feature on my Windows server 2008 R2, but
>   not sure if it will ask me to reboot or something. That server
>   shoudn't be rebooted. Is it safe to proceed?

Yes, it's safe per those instructions and it states it will not require a reboot.

In the event it does require a reboot, it will not force you to reboot it right then so you'd be able to do so when it's safe to do so with coordination in your environment.